# Convert AnsibleUnsafeText to String

Tags: ansible

I am using the ansible shell module to compare the chain of 2 SSL certificate with openssl (they have the same chain):

```
openssl x509 -issuer -noout -in Certiticate1
openssl x509 -issuer -noout -in Certiticate2
```

I register the output in variables chain_from_certificate1 and chain_from_certificate2 then i compares there standard output:

```
- name: Compare the Chain
    fail:
      msg: Error The chains aren't the same
    when: chain_from_certificate1.stdout !=  chain_from_certificate2.stdout
```

Ansible tell me that the chains are not similar (and it's false because they are).

I think that the issue came from the comparison operator because the type of the variable are "AnsibleUnsafeText" and not string.

My question how to compare 2 AnsibleUnsafeText ? and it's necessary to convert them to string before comparison ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you manually confirm the output of `openssl x509 -issuer -noout -in Certiticate1`
and `openssl x509 -issuer -noout -in Certiticate2` are the same?

Comment: @akane Yes i aleardy check manually and they are the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is due to non existing variable attribute.
Most likely `chain_from_certificate1` and `chain_from_certificate2` don't have `stdout`

Did you try debug by printing the variables?
With `stdout`:
Did this throw similar failure?

```
    - name: print variable
      debug:
        msg: "{{ chain_from_certificate1.stdout }}"
```

Without `stdout`:
What is output of this?
Will this print same output as of manually execute `openssl x509 -issuer -noout -in Certiticate1`?

```
    - name: print variable
      debug:
        msg: "{{ chain_from_certificate1 }}"
```

My assumption is that the script set the value of `stdout` in `chain_from_certificate1` and `chain_from_certificate2` rather than the `stdout: <value>`. Therefor `stdout` do not exist as attribute.
Or `chain_from_certificate1` and `chain_from_certificate2` contain another data structure.

The key is to print them out.